# read file and actionPerformed in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, readfile

I am working on part of a program. In this NameFrame class, I need to use the swing to graph some inputs from a class called NameRecord. And this program works in a way such that if I type in a name into the text box and clicking the “Graph” button; searches for the data associated with the name then asks the NameGraph class to add it to the currently displayed names. If the requested name is not found, have your program beep.

I want to add some storage to the list of names that are currently being displayed in NameGraph class. I am not sure which part of my code should do that. And I don't know how to ask the clear one, clear all, and search button to perform what I wrote in the comment.

My read method is not working as I expected. I got that from other answers here. It gives me an error when I run it.

I am really confused right now. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

 private NameGraph myGraph;
 private JTextField inputField;
 private JTextArea displayArea;
 private static final boolean SEARCH = false;
 NameRecord[] namesArray;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of NameFrame
 */
public NameFrame() {
    myGraph = new NameGraph();
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myGraph);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    inputField = new JTextField(25);

    inputField.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(inputField);

    JButton b = new JButton("Graph");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b);

    b = new JButton("Search");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b);

    b = new JButton("Clear All");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b);

    b = new JButton("Clear One");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b);

    b = new JButton("Quit");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b);

    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonPanel);

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NameFrame f = new NameFrame();

    f.read("names-data.txt");
    f.setTitle("NameSurfer");
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = e.getActionCommand();

    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("graph")) {
        doGraph();
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("search")) {
        //– use the text in the text field and print to standard output a list of all
        //names that contain the string as a substring along with the highest rank for the
        //name for any year.
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("clear all")){
        setVisible(false);
        //– remove all names from the NameGraph

    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("clear one")){

    //remove the name that was added to the NameGraph earliest.
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        // This is the response to the Enter Key pressed in inputField.
        doGraph();
    }
}

public void doGraph() {
    String s = inputField.getText();
    NameRecord r = new NameRecord(s);
    if (r == null) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    } else {
        myGraph.addName(r);
    }

    inputField.setText("");
}

public void read(String filename) {

    try {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        int i = 0;
        int num = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine().trim());
        namesArray = new NameRecord[num];

        String inputString;
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            inputString = inFile.nextLine();
            namesArray[i] = new NameRecord(inputString);
            displayArea.append(namesArray[i].toString() + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io);
    }
}  // readFile()

}
```

~~~~~~~

edited:
This is the problematic read method.

```
    public void read(String fileName) {
    File theFile = new File(fileName);
    HashDict dictionary = new HashDict(); 

    try{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(theFile); 

        while (reader.hasNext()){
            //creates a NameRecord for each line of file 
            String input = reader.nextLine();
            NameRecord r = new NameRecord(input); 
            String name = r.getName(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                 decades[i] = r.getRank(i);

            }
            dictionary.add(name, decades);       
        }             
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.print("File not found");
    }
```

The error message is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at NameFrame.read(NameFrame.java:133)
at NameFrame.main(NameFrame.java:76)
```

Where did I have the null pointer? Why would I have it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Neither `NameGraph` nor `NameRecord` are defined. Hard code some data to replace the file. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question? 4) *"It gives me an error when I run it."* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: That is very helpful. I edited my question based on your suggestions. Thank you very much.